# Optimizing the number of robots to be used for a certain task

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

We have $N$ buttons numbered $1$,$2$ .. $N$. Our aim is to press each of the buttons at least once in the minimum time possible. For that purpose we choose $m$ robots. These robots can press one of the buttons in each second. But when two or more robots try to press the same button at the same time, that button won't be pressed (the robots will know that the button couldn't be pressed). Under the restriction that all the robots should be coded identically (i.e. they should execute the same instructions), what value of $m$ will you choose and how will you code them?

For example, if we choose $m=1$ and instruct the robot to press the $i$th button in the $i$th second, it will take a total of $N$ seconds before all the buttons are pressed. If we choose $m=2$ and instruct the robots to press button $1$ or $2$ uniformly at random until they have successfully pressed one of those(if one of them is successful in pressing one, then the other is automatically successful in pressing the other), and then sequentially press every other button (for example, if the robot succeeded in pressing button $1$, then it will try(successfully) to press the buttons numbered $3$, $5$,.. in the next seconds), then it will take an average time of $2+\frac{N-2}{2}$ seconds before each button is pressed.

Comment: do you want a deterministic or probabilistic solution? The one you gave above does have average time of 2 + N-2/2 seconds but it can be much much worse since it is after all a random algorithm

Comment: well, no deterministic algorithm will work if $m>1$. I am only worried about the average time

Comment: You could make it deterministic. You haven't given the amount of time between robots starting. So if you stagger their starting times (by a really small amount) and add a bunch of if statements to check for pushed buttons you could make an m = n solution which would do the job in basically N + n*(stagger-time) seconds

Comment: All the robots should be coded identically (which includes the starting time). Time is assumed to be discrete(this is not real life scenario).

Comment: One more question, can they share any sort of communication (aka a global variable) between themselves? I assume not otherwise this would again reduce to a simple deterministic problem

Comment: No. This is more of a puzzle than a coding problem

Comment: It seems sort of implicit in some of what you write, but you never state it explicitly: Is the aim to minimize the *expected* time taken to push all buttons?

Comment: yeah..that is the way I am looking at the problem as of now : to minimize the expected time before all the buttons are pressed at least once

Comment: Note the edit link underneath the question; clarifications to the question should preferably be edited into the question itself, so that people don't have to read through all the comments to properly understand the question.

Comment: In your examples, each robot only uses the information about which buttons it itself pressed (and whether it did so successfully). Can the robots also use the information which buttons the other robots pressed?

Answer (score 1):

For small $N$, the details of the optimal algorithm seem likely to be complicated; they're probably best determined by dynamic programming. However, for large $N$, the following algorithm covers all buttons in $3$ seconds [asymptotically almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Asymptotically_almost_surely).

Take a very large number of robots, i.e. $m\gg N$, and let them press any of the buttons with probability $p=1/m$ each, and no button with probability $1-Np=1-N/m$. (This last probability is non-negative since $m\gg N$.) The probability that a particular button is pressed exactly once, and thus the expected fraction of buttons that get pressed exactly once, is

$$
mp(1-p)^{m-1}=m\cdot\frac1m\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{m-1}=\left(1-\frac1m\right)^{m-1}\to_{m\to\infty}\frac1{\mathrm e}\;.
$$

For large $N$, the distribution is sharply peaked around this expected value, so the fraction of buttons successfully pressed is almost certain to be greater than $1/3$. Now let the robots that successfully pressed a button press further buttons according to some predefined scheme. (For instance, let the robots plan their actions by virtually acting in succession in the order of the numbers of the buttons they pressed in the first second, and let each robot press the button with the lowest number that hasn't been pressed either in a previous second or in a previous planning step.)

Comment: So you are trying to give each robot an identity (whose absence was the root of the problem) using the first step and you make sure enough robots gets their own identity by deploying a very large number of robots.Nice. Thanks, but.. 
The robots cannot know which buttons are yet to pressed. They only know about what they did. As frogeyedpeas said there are no global variables.We can modify your algorithm by just telling the robots to attempt each successive button in the next seconds. But I am pretty sure it won't finish in $O(1)$ (Or does it? worst case is ${2N}/{3}$)

Comment: @bleh: That's what I was asking about in my comment under the question: whether they know what the others did. I'm not sure why you mention the worst case; you said you were interested in the expected time. I suspect that the expected time in your modification of the algorithm would be $O(\log N)$.

Comment: Sorry about that. Before I could see that comment, you had already written the answer. I think your suspicion can be partly justified like this:Let $e_n$ denote the expected maximal length of string of non pressed buttons(zeros) when some $n$ buttons are pressed(one) among $3n$ buttons. Then $e_{n+1}\geq e_n+\frac{1}{3 (3 n)}$ (consider forming a binary string A of length 3n+3, by appending 3 random bits at the end of string B of length 3n). The maximal length is increased if the first added bit is zero.....

Comment: ......and the maximal substring of B is at its end (this happens with a probability of at least $1/3n$ because if the maximal 0-substring is of length k then all the last 3n-k+1 bits are equally likely to be its end.) Hence we proved that lower bound. So the question now is that can we beat $O(log(n))$. Also it turns out that $e_N$ is exactly (if I didn't make any mistakes, i just used inclusion-exclusion principle and the fact that mean=integral of complementary CDF ) $\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{2 N} \sum _{i=1}^{N+1} (-1)^{i-1} C_i^{N+1} C_N^{3 N-\text{ik}}}{C_N^{3 N}}$.